# Remove php 7.3 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, package-management, php

I accidentally installed php7.3 and it took over from php 7.2, but now some of the custom modules I use on my website have started to produce errors.

Is it possible to remove php7.3 and have everything that uses php default back to php 7.2?

Cheers

Comment: Hi Peter, welcome to AskUbuntu!  Have you tried `sudo apt-get install php7.2`?

Answer (score 3):

To only remove PHP 7.3 and keep PHP 7.2 which was already installed you could do a

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.3.*
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then you do not lose all PHP versions and kan keep the site running. Do make sure your website is using the PHP 7.2 version of course i.e. make sure the web server calls 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try, first, to remove completely php:

```
sudo apt-get remove –purge ^php
sudo apt-get purge ^php
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then install php7.2

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2
```

Comment: if php7.2 is still on the server should I remove all the php versions?

Comment: In my opinion, it's the easiest way to keep the system in order; sometimes it also solves some issues with module enabling. Remember to backup `php.ini` if it does not point to some local file outside php installation path

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable php7.3:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.3
```

and enable php7.2:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.2
```